# How to Skip Numbers In Each Iteration Loop String in Python?

Tags: python

I'm very new to this: but I have this string:

```
urls = ['http://example.com/page_%s.html' % page for page in xrange(0,50)]
```

which runs from 0,1,2,3 ... 50.

The question is how can i make run by skipping 5 number in each iteration?

The number should run like this: 0, 5, 10, 15 ... 50.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just adding the 5 as another argument to xrange should do that

```
urls = ['http://example.com/page_%s.html' % page for page in xrange(0,50,5)]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
urls = map('http://example.com/page_{}.html'.format, range(0, 50, 5))
```

`range` and `xrange` take an optional `step` argument as the third parameter.